# Does QueueClient.CreateFromConnectionString cache internal connection?

Tags: performance, asp.net-core, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I have an HTTP endpoint in an ASP.NET Core app that sends a couple of messages to Azure Service Bus.

Right now, the controller action code does this:

```
var client = QueueClient.CreateFromConnectionString(this.connectionString, entityPath);
await client.SendAsync(message);
```

The QueueClient that is created doesn't support `Dispose` so I'm wondering how long its lifetime should be? I create a new one per HTTP request. Does the QueueClient's `CreateFromConnectionString` method cache internal connections to the service bus? What is the optimal solution here? I'm asking because I've been receiving `TimeoutExceptions` from the service bus lately during traffic spikes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-performance-improvements#reusing-factories-and-clients) mentioned about Service Bus client:

> Service Bus client objects, such as QueueClient or MessageSender, are created through a **MessagingFactory** object, which also **provides internal management of connections**. **You should not close messaging factories or queue, topic, and subscription clients after you send a message, and then re-create them when you send the next message**. **Closing a messaging factory deletes the connection to the Service Bus service, and a new connection is established when recreating the factory. Establishing a connection is an expensive operation** that you can avoid by re-using the same factory and client objects for multiple operations. **You can safely use the QueueClient object for sending messages from concurrent asynchronous operations and multiple threads**.

> I'm asking because I've been receiving TimeoutExceptions from the service bus lately during traffic spikes.

As mentioned in the official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-messaging-exceptions#timeoutexception) about Service Bus messaging **TimeoutException**:

> A TimeoutException indicates that a user-initiated operation is taking longer than the operation timeout. You should check the value of the [ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.defaultconnectionlimit) property, as hitting this limit can also cause a [TimeoutException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.timeoutexception.aspx).

I assumed that you could try to increase [OperationTimeout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.messagingfactorysettings.operationtimeout?view=azureservicebus-4.0.0#Microsoft_ServiceBus_Messaging_MessagingFactorySettings_OperationTimeout) and add retry logic as follows to build your QueueClient and reuse this QueueClient object.

```
var builder = new ServiceBusConnectionStringBuilder("{ServicesBusConnectionString}")
{
    OperationTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5)
};
var messagingFactory = MessagingFactory.CreateFromConnectionString(builder.ToString());
QueueClient queueClient = messagingFactory.CreateQueueClient("{queueName}");
queueClient.RetryPolicy = new RetryExponential(
                TimeSpan.Zero,
                TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
                2);
queueClient.SendAsync("{BrokeredMessage}");
```

Comment: I've read that before, but I'm not using MessagingFactory directly. Instead I'm using the static QueueClient.CreateFromConnectionString method. Does this close the MessagingFactory or is there a single static one used by the static QueueClient class? This is where the docs fail. Perhaps I'll use the code you've provided if no one else can clear this up.

Comment: I will also add that I did just increase the DefaultConnectionLimit, though everything I've read indicates that is only for HTTP calls and ASB uses a proprietary TCP protocol.